# Why is my laptop only producing sound when the headphones should be active?

Tags: windows-7, skype, speakers

I think Skype may have corrupted my laptop speakers somehow. The other day I was listening to music on my headphones when a coworker started sending me IMs. Whenever the alert sound played, the music and alert would both come out through the laptop speakers for a second instead of the headphones.

Now sound only comes out through the speakers when skype is playing sounds, or if I right click the volume control, select Playback Devices and test the headphones. So if I play music it's silent. If I go into Skype and dial the sound test call the music will start coming through the speakers.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Win7 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\ (Sound)

Do you have some kind of default speakers listed there?  If they are the laptop speakers, try clicking on Set Default.

If that fails, try deleting your Sound or Speakers or both from Device Manager, rebooting, and let Windows detect and install them again.